# Tag merge results are #eaeaea on #eaeaea on Meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, moderators, meta

This is what I see after merging two tags on Meta:

[image: Merge Results]

Please review the CSS on Meta and make sure all text is properly contrasted with its background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next production build.